# How to count all occurrences of an element in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have the following entries in my MongoDB.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b81b"), "name" : "a", "time" : NumberLong("1412774562000"), "location" : "DE" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b81c"), "name" : "b", "time" : NumberLong("1412774562020"), "location" : "DE" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b81d"), "name" : "c", "time" : NumberLong("1412774562040"), "location" : "US" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b81e"), "name" : "d", "time" : NumberLong("1412774562060"), "location" : "AU" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5474af69d4b28042fb63b81f"), "name" : "e", "time" : NumberLong("1412774562080"), "location" : "CN" }
```

As a result, I need to know how often **each** specific "location" can be found in the database e.g.

```
{"DE": "2",
 "US": "1",
 "AU": "1",
 "CN": "1"}
```

I have no information about all the different locations in the database so querying after a known location for example

```
db.c.find({"location": "DE"})
```

would not solve my problem.

Comment: aggregation is your answer, you can find a lot of samples in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of the `aggregation` pipeline with a `group` and `project` stage operators.

```
db.c.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$location","count":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"location":"$_id","occurance":"$count"}}
])
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get an output like mentioned above? {"DE":"2","US":"1"...}

Comment: Yes. It is possible using map reduce but it is better to do the transformation on the application code.